# Is it possible to convert a query with the nativeQuery flag (subquery in from clause)?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, subquery, hql

Below I have created a query that I need to get rid of the nativeQuery flags. Is it possible?

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "" +
        " select name from (" +
        "    select distinct t.name" +
        "    from my_table t" +
        "    order by t.name asc" +
        " ) as name" +
        " where :name='' or upper(name) = upper(:name) or upper(name) like ('%' || upper(:name) || '%')" +
        " order by case when (:name='' or upper(name) like (upper(:name) || '%')) then 0 else 1 end")
Page<String> search(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use the `CONCAT` function instead of the `||` concat operator like this:

```
@Query("select distinct t.name" +
       "from MyEntity t" +
       "where :name='' or upper(t.name) = upper(:name) or upper(t.name) like concat(concat('%', upper(:name)), '%')" +
       " order by case when (:name='' or upper(t.name) like concat(upper(:name), '%')) then 0 else 1 end")
Page<String> search(@Param("name") String name, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: When you insert the Query you specified, the application will not build. There is a problem with the `where` after the  `order by`.

Exception message: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: where near line 1, column 114 [select distinct t.name from MyTable t order by t.name asc where :name='' or upper(t.name) = upper(:name) or upper(t.name) like concat(concat('%', upper(:name)), '%') order by case when (:name='' or upper(t.name) like concat(upper(:name), '%')) then 0 else 1 end]`

Comment: Wrote too fast, I updated the the query in the answer.

Comment: In updated code, you removed alphabetical sorting. Sorted result is necessary. Updated code still doesn't work. Error message: `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Comment: You are removing this alphabetical ordering in your original query as well. You only order the inner subquery, but that order is completely irrelevant in the overall result as you order again in the outer query. I wasn't aware of this `DISTINCT` limitation in PostgreSQL. I think in this case you must use `DISTINCT ON` or `GROUP BY`, but since you downvoted my attempts to help you, good luck finding the answer yourself.